# a counterexample of covering projection

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X=S^1\times S^1\times\cdots$ be a countable product of 1-spheres and for $n\geq 1$ let $\tilde{X_n}=R^n\times S^1\times S^1\times\cdots$.Define $p_n:\tilde{X_n}\rightarrow X$ by 
$$p_n(t_1,\cdots,t_n,z_1,z_2,\cdots)=(e^{t_1},\cdots,e^{t_n},z_1,z_2,\cdots)$$
Let $\tilde{X}=\vee \tilde{X_n}$ and define $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ so that $p\mid \tilde{X_n}=p_n$.The components of $\tilde{X}$ are the spaces $\tilde{X_n}$ and the map $p \mid \tilde{X_n}=p_n:\tilde{X_n}\rightarrow X$ is a covering projection.However,$p$ is not a covering projection,because no open subset of $X$ is evenly covered by $p$.Can someone interpret it in more details?

Comment: Just to be sure, I suppose that by $\vee X_n$ you mean their disjoint union ? And what makes you think that `no open subset of $X$ is evenly covered by $p$' ? I think on the contrary that $X$ is evenly covered by an countable dicrete fibre.

Answer (score 3):

Let $U\subseteq X$ be a basic open set.  Recall that in the product topology, the basic open sets are of the form $$U = U_1\times U_2\times U_3\times\ldots \times U_N\times S^1\times S^1 \ldots$$ where each $U_i\subseteq S^1$ is open.

We will show that $U$ is not evenly covered, meaning $p^{-1}(U)$ is not a disjoint union of sets each mapped homeomorphically onto $U$.  Note that since every open set is built out of basic ones, and because shrinking and evenly covered open set keeps it evenly covered, this will show that *no* open subset of $U$ is evenly covered, so $p$ is *not* a covering map.

Given $U$ as above, by shrinking each $U_i$, we may assume each $U_i$ is connected.  Now, assume for a contradiction that $p^{-1}(U) = \coprod_\alpha V_\alpha$ for which $p|_{V_\alpha}$ is a homeomorphism onto $U$.

Since $U$ is connected, each $V_\alpha$ is connected, so each $V_\alpha$ is a subset of $X_n = \mathbb{R}^n\times S^1\ldots\times S^1$ for some $n$.  Let's focus on $n = N+1$ and consider only a particular $V_\alpha$s contained in $X_{N+1}$.  We must have $p|_{V_\alpha} = p_{N+1}|_{V_\alpha}$ a homeomorphism onto $U$.  Let $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be the projection of $V_\alpha$ onto the $N+1$st coordinate.  Then $p_{N+1}|_V:V\subseteq \mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ must be a homeomorphism, which is clearly impossible.

This contradiction implies $U$ is not evenly covered, so $p$ is not a covering map.